# left non equi join linq

Tags: c#, linq

I have a list of objects in table tblB which is retrieved from db in following format.

```
public class playdata
    {
        public string consumerid { get; set; }
        public string play_time { get; set; }
        public string genre{ get; set; }
        .
        .
        .
        public int mycounter{ get; set; }
    }
```

I have a table tblA which has a column colA which has int from 0 to 1000.

**I wish to create a linq query similar to sql as below..**

```
Select x.i as numindex, y.consumerid,y.play_time,y.genre
From
(Select colA as i from tblA) x 
left join 
(
 Select consumerid, play_time,genre,mycounter from tblB
)y on y.mycounter > x.i
```

I tried the following unsuccessfully..

I came to find that Enumerable.Range(0, 1001) generated a numeric series so no need to get that table data..

```
List<playdata> plays = .....



 var q= (from s in Enumerable.Range(0, 1001)
           join p in plays on s < p.mycounter into t
           from rt in t.DefaultIfEmpty() select new{
    numindex=s,
    consumerid=p.consumerid,
    play_time =p.play_time,
    genre=p.genre
    }).ToList();
```

I see two errors in second line..

p is not in scope of left side of equals .. I have also tried..p.mycounter>s with same result.

The other error is in into where it shows.. expected contextual keyword equals

The errors go away if I change the second line to..

```
join p in plays on s equals p.mycounter into t
```

All help is sincerely appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use the alternative way of representing left outer join in LINQ:

```
var q =
    (from i in Enumerable.Range(0, 1001)
     from p in plays.Where(x => x.mycounter > i).DefaultIfEmpty()
     select new
     {
         numindex = i,
         consumerid = p?.consumerid,
         play_time = p?.play_time,
         genre = p?.genre
     }).ToList();
```

Note that in LINQ to Objects you have to account for right side of the left outer join returning `null` when there is no matching element, otherwise you'll get `NullReferenceException`.

Comment: wow.. without any join and on directive..also.. could u show where I can read more on the p?.genre style of handling null,Tx

Comment: It's the C#6 [null conditional operator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn986595.aspx).

Comment: aha.. that's vs2015, in case of vs2103.. this 'p== null ? String.Empty : p.genre)' ought to work?? in case the parameter is int or long, I will have to change String.Empty with null, will that require my class 'playdata' to change as well such as int becoming int?, what would happen in case of long

Comment: You can always use `? : ` operator. For strings, `p == null ? string.Empty : p.genre` works. For value types, just apply cast to a nullable type to one of the operands, e.g. `p == null ? null : (int?)p.myintid`

Comment: I searched for that for SO LONG... Thank you, good sir! This is actually a way to make a left join with whatever condition I want, finally I found it!